# Angular JS - View not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, controller

Evening,

I am struggling to integrate view into my code,was wondering if someone could please help me troubleshoot. I've exhausted the little i do know.

I've got it working offline without views (controller in the index.html) and it looks like this

[Local Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1scd1.png)

Here is the plunk version of what I couldn't get working locally

http://plnkr.co/edit/f7XVqxnVzDjGd17a4SMB?p=preview

It has something to do with my HomeController.js file because it is currently redirecting via "otherwise" in app.js as without it nothing shows

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module("DraftApp", ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/players', {
      controller: "HomeController",
      templateUrl: "main.html"
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/players'
    });
});
```

**HomeController**

```
app.controller("HomeController", ["$scope", "players",
  function($scope, players) {
    players.success(function(data) {
      $scope.players = data;
    });
    $scope.filters = {};
    $scope.predicate = 'PTS';
    $scope.reverse = true;
    $scope.order = function(predicate) {
        $scope.reverse = ($scope.predicate === predicate) ? !$scope.reverse : true;
        $scope.predicate = predicate;
    };
  }
]);`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a spelling mistake, so the controller is not getting laoded,

Change,

**From**

```
<script src="players.js"></script>
```

**To**

```
<script src="player.js"></script>
```

Working [Applciation](http://plnkr.co/edit/loZn4FujWcicg8KYpMg4?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks Sajeetharan, two mistakes

1. was the one you found
2. other was 
   <tr class="each" ng-repeat="player in players | filter:filters | orderBy:predicate:reverse">

to

<tr class="each" ng-repeat="player in myplayers | filter:filters | orderBy:predicate:reverse">